# Excel keeps "running" while asking SAP GUI to export spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, sap-gui

I have a problem with a Excel VBA code that constantly get stuck in 'running' when I execute the code, see figure [image: Stuck Excel;]

The Purpose of the code is:

1. Log into SAP
2. Execute a transaction (in this case IW73)
3. Export a Spreadsheet as .txt

The Problem after closing the SAP session the Excel get stuck in "Running". We have tried running it on different computers with the same (Stuck in 'Running') error.

Code:

```
 Sub Logontrial()
 Dim SapGuiApp As Object
 Dim oConnection As Object
 Dim SAPCon As Object, SAPSesi As Object
 Dim SapGuiAuto As Object, SAPApp As Object


 If SapGuiApp Is Nothing Then
  Set SapGuiApp = CreateObject("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")
 End If

 If oConnection Is Nothing Then
    Set oConnection = SapGuiApp.OpenConnection("5.1.1 AP1 ERP Production", True)
 End If

  If SAPSesi Is Nothing Then
     Set SAPSesi = oConnection.Children(0)
  End If

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  With SAPSesi

SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").Text = "500"
SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").Text = "UserName"
SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").Text = "Password"
SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").Text = "EN"
SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").SetFocus
SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").caretPosition = 2
SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0


 '  start extraction
   On Error GoTo Resume1
   ' DoEvents
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nIW73"
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSWERK-LOW").Text = "GB10"
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSWERK-LOW").SetFocus
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSWERK-LOW").caretPosition = 4
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[11]/menu[2]").Select
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-SELFLAG[1,0]").Select
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-SELFLAG[1,0]").SetFocus
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "DataImport1.txt"
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 15
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/n"
   SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

   Set SAPSesi = Nothing
   Set oConnection = Nothing
   Set SapGuiApp = Nothing
   End With

  ' This part after closing the SAP session it get stuck.

  Resume1:

   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Set SAPSesi = Nothing
   Set oConnection = Nothing
   Set SapGuiApp = Nothing
  Exit Sub
  End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

//Patrick

Comment: I don't use SAP GUI scripting, but wouldn't you close the various SAP connections and Object(Quit maybe) before setting them to nothing?

Comment: Hi MacroMarc, How would you close the connection then? Do you have an example I could try?

Comment: I dont get SAPScripting here, and we use Process Runner to inteface between Excel VBA and SAP, so i can't answer that question. I just put that comment as a suggestion.

Comment: I assume there's a mix between current Excel running and Excel opened by SAP GUI export. Consequently, I have edited the title to something more appropriate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exported file opens after macro completes - unwanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729968/exported-file-opens-after-macro-completes-unwanted)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** *This is not quality code, and most probably one day someone can put some bunch of hate towards you.*

Before finding something better, try the following, it should work. Simply write `End` here:

```
Set SAPSesi = Nothing
Set oConnection = Nothing
Set SapGuiApp = Nothing
End
```

Then look for a better solution.

Comment: Hi Vityata, I am not too experienced coding VBA but as long as it works I'm fine. Sorry but Excel get stuck even though I added the `end ` statement as you suggested.

Comment: @Patrick - That's strange. Try to add it exaclty after    `SAPSesi.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0`

Comment: I tried that too. The code is executed on Excel 2013. If the code itself is "fine" could it be due to any security settings or how the Connection to SAP is disabled that cause it to get "Stuck"?