# Export SAP Data won't open workbook while running

Tags: excel, vba, scripting, sap-gui

I wrote a code to export data from SAP to an Excel workbook. To do that I open the transaction (IW28 in this case), export the file and save it to a specified location. When the file is opened, I want to copy the data from the exported sheet to my own sheet.

The problem is that the exported sheet won't open while I'm running the macro. When I add a breakpoint in my code, the exported sheet opens when the macro stops. Without this breakpoint the exported sheets only opens after the macro had finished.

```
'Laden van de data uit transactie IW28 naar de sheet
Dim lastcolumn As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'SAP Variant
SapVariant = "Variant"

'Transaction
Name = IW28

'Current File Location
Map = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

If Not IsObject(SapApp) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set SapApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
   Set Connection = SapApp.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject SapApp, "on"
End If

'Check if file is already open, if so then close the file
If IsOpen(Name & ".xlsx") = True Then Workbooks(Name & ".xlsx").Close

'Open Transaction
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/N" & Name
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

'Choose Variant
On Error Resume Next
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[2]/menu[0]/menu[0]").Select
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtV-LOW").Text = SapVariant

'Check if variant excists
If Not Err.Number = 0 Then
    VarMsgbox = MsgBox("Selecteer variant " & SapVariant & ", dubbelklik om deze te selecteren en klik dan hieronder op ok (niet eerder!)", vbOKCancel, "Selecteer variant")
    If VarMsgbox = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
Else
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtENAME-LOW").Text = ""
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtV-LOW").caretPosition = 10
    session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 8
End If

'Execute Variant
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8

'Select all data in SAP
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").SelectAll

'Export to Excel
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").contextMenu
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

'Add filename and path
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = Name & ".xlsx"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = Map
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press

'Determine lastrow of sheet
Lastrow = Workbooks(Name & ".xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B99999").End(xlUp).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Name).Range("A8:C99999").ClearContents

Workbooks(Name & ".xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C" & Lastrow).Copy

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Name).Range("A8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Start").Activate

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Please look at the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729968/exported-file-opens-after-macro-completes-unwanted

Comment: I checked it out and tried this "Go Check on top right corner... click on the TV > Settings > Interactive > Quick Info and use accesibility mode.", but without result. The other sollutions are to prevent excel from opening the workbooks at the end. My question is that I would like to open the created workbook while running the code, so I can pick up the data from the created workbook and paste it into my own Excelfile.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following program construction:

```
Public Name as String

Sub Makro1()
 'Laden van de data uit transactie IW28 naar de sheet
 Dim lastcolumn As Long

 . . .

 session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
 call Makro2
End Sub

Sub Makro2()
 'Determine lastrow of sheet
 Lastrow = Workbooks(Name &    .xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B99999").End(xlUp).Row

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Name).Range("A8:C99999").ClearContents

 Workbooks(Name & ".xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C" & Lastrow).Copy

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Name).Range("A8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Start").Activate

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```