# How to prevent SAP from opening the exported files when the code is over?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

The code opens the transaction and saves the file with data from SAP.
The problem is that when the code is performed, the exported file starts to open itself.

```
Sub MRN()   
Dim SapGuiAuto
Dim SetApp
Dim Connection
Dim Session

   'connecting to SAP

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SetApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = SetApp.Children(0)
Set Session = Connection.Children(0)

Plant = "Ru64"
My_Path = "N:\OF\Order Handling\reserve\"

' entering data to the transaction

Session.FindById("wnd[0]").Maximize
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nzcor_mrn1"
Session.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_BUKRS").Text = Plant
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_STDAT").Text = "30.04.2019"
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txt%_S_WERKS_%_APP_%-TEXT").SetFocus
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txt%_S_WERKS_%_APP_%-TEXT").CaretPosition = 5
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%P123019_1000").Press
    Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1101/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1109:SAPLMYPOP:1103/chkSNIWE-BMATP").Selected = False
    Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1101/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1109:SAPLMYPOP:1103/chkSNIWE-BBPRH").Selected = True
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1101/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1109:SAPLMYPOP:1103/chkSNIWE-BVMMP").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1101/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1109:SAPLMYPOP:1103/chkSNIWE-BVJMP").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1101/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1109:SAPLMYPOP:1103/chkSNIWE-BSTPS").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1101/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1109:SAPLMYPOP:1103/chkSNIWE-BVMSP").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1101/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1109:SAPLMYPOP:1103/chkSNIWE-BVJSP").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1101/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1109:SAPLMYPOP:1103/chkSNIWE-BVERP").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1101/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1109:SAPLMYPOP:1103/chkSNIWE-BVMVP").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1101/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1109:SAPLMYPOP:1103/chkSNIWE-BVJVP").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1101/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1109:SAPLMYPOP:1103/chkSNIWE-BBPRS").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1101/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1109:SAPLMYPOP:1103/chkSNIWE-BBPS1").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1101/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1109:SAPLMYPOP:1103/chkSNIWE-BVJBS").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1101/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1109:SAPLMYPOP:1103/chkSNIWE-BBPH1").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1101/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1109:SAPLMYPOP:1103/chkSNIWE-BVJBH").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/radSNIWE-BREPV").SetFocus
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/radSNIWE-BREPV").Select
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/radSNIWE-BNIWE").SetFocus
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/radSNIWE-BNIWE").Select
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/radP_VBROG").Select
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_UPDAT").SetFocus
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_UPDAT").Selected = True
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%P176039_1000").Press
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1301/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1309:SAPLMYPOP:1303/chkSNIWE-UBPRS").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1301/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1309:SAPLMYPOP:1303/chkSNIWE-UBPS1").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1301/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1309:SAPLMYPOP:1303/chkSNIWE-UVJBS").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1301/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1309:SAPLMYPOP:1303/chkSNIWE-UBPRH").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1301/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1309:SAPLMYPOP:1303/chkSNIWE-UBPH1").Selected = True
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1301/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1309:SAPLMYPOP:1303/chkSNIWE-UVJBH").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1301/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1309:SAPLMYPOP:1303/chkSNIWE-CHDOC").Selected = False
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_1301/tabpPIP/ssubSUB_1309:SAPLMYPOP:1303/chkSNIWE-CHDOC").SetFocus
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VARI").SetFocus
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VARI").CaretPosition = 0
Session.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 2
Session.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 4
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,14]").SetFocus
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,14]").CaretPosition = 6
Session.FindById("wnd[1]").SendVKey 2
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VARI").Text = "/DETAIL_RU"
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").Press





'Saving the file
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[43]").Press
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = Plant & ".XLSX"
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = My_Path

Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").CaretPosition = 0
Session.FindById("wnd[1]").SendVKey 4
Session.FindById("wnd[2]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").SetFocus
Session.FindById("wnd[2]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").CaretPosition = 0
Session.FindById("wnd[2]").SendVKey 4
Session.FindById("wnd[3]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").SetFocus
Session.FindById("wnd[3]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").CaretPosition = 0
Session.FindById("wnd[3]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press
Session.FindById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").Press
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press




If InStr(1, Session.FindById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text, "exist", 1) <> 0 Then

Application.SendKeys ("^s")
Application.SendKeys ("^s")
Application.SendKeys ("^s")
Application.SendKeys ("^s")
End If

End Sub
```

1) I tried to close the export file using the code. And at the moment when the code runs, it shows that this file is closed. But it opens again when the code is over.

2) I also deleted the export file, but then there is a message that file is not found.
Obviously, SAP launches everything it has imported after the code is performed.

The code above is a small part of the whole program. So in the end, I have a bunch of such files popping up.

How to block this nasty feature?

Comment: I can only refer to a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729968/exported-file-opens-after-macro-completes-unwanted/40759971#40759971

Comment: @ScriptMan You are the MAN! Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exported file opens after macro completes - unwanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729968/exported-file-opens-after-macro-completes-unwanted)